# Datatables how to search and paginate server side

Tags: javascript, java, spring, datatables

I have a Java rest api which I can get paginated results like this:

> /allusers?page=1&text=searchkeyword&pageSize=50

I am trying to implement the frontend using datatables(also open to other library suggstions) But cant seem to figure out how do do I send the page and search keywords using Datatables server side processing:

This is the example code from their website, how do I pass the parameters here? So when user clicks next page or search for a keyword it makes the relavent backend call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing"
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things you can/must do to set up your pagination.

1. All your columns must contain at least attribute "data":

   ```
   var aoColumns = [ { "mData": "c1-data-attr", "sName": "c1-name-attr", "sClass": "c1-class-attr"}]
   ```
2. Defining a dataSrcFunction, which will automatically receive as a parameter the JSON with your paginated table from your API response. The return (json.data) shall contain the values for each column defined in aoColumns by their mData atributte value.

   ```
   var dataSrcFunct = function (json) {
       console.log(json);
       //manipulate your JSON here
       return json.data;
   };
   ```
3. Defining an errorFunction that will execute when the response is not OK.

These parameters will go in your configuration like this:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": { 
            "url": "/allusers?page=1&text=searchkeyword&pageSize=50",
            "dataSrc": dataSrcFunction,
            "error": errorFunction
        },
        "aoColumns": aoColumns
);
```

Comment: I see you are still hardcoding all parameters in the url. This is not an answer

Comment: Sorry, I got which parameters you were refering to now. As far as I know, Datatables' serverside will automatically complete your endpoint with its own parameters that contains the columns defined in aoColumns and values such as "start" and "length" (from what you can get page number and size). I know that from it you won't be able to map it to Pageable.